# Disable Power Prompt When Shutting Down Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: power-management, shutdown, lightdm

I am running Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.7 LTS inside a KVM/QEMU VM.

I manage this (and other VMs) via the `virsh` CLI, including starting and shutting down the VM.

No matter what I do, when I issue the shutdown command, it hangs. When I open the console to look for the reason - I see it is stuck on the Power Menu prompt (Restart, Shutdown, etc.).

I tried to follow a few guides to resolve this and it works if I issue the command as a logged in user, but I want to shutdown the VM using the `virsh` command alone.

How can I make the changes to the shutdown behavior in LightDM's settings, without any user logged in?

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 is EOL in April and there will be no support or updates past then, Maybe time for an upgrade.

Comment: @David, I would gladly upgrade it to the latest LTS, but these specific machines are running ROS Kinetic, which requires Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You may want to look into this ESM feature when 16.04 does pass on. https://ubuntu.com/security/esm

Comment: Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 14.04 and 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a little bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19545/43926